# Foreign Key constraint on fixed value field

Tags: foreign-key, sybase, odbc

Note: I am a developer...

I have an Asset table that has many codes that are foreign keys into a second table OutlineFiles. The OutlineFiles table has Type and Code as the primary key. The foreign key constraint need to look like this...

```
ALTER TABLE "dbo"."Assets" 
ADD CONSTRAINT "Locations" FOREIGN KEY ( "LN", "LocationCode" ASC ) 
REFERENCES "dbo"."OutlineFiles" ( "Type", "Code" );

ALTER TABLE "dbo"."Assets" 
ADD CONSTRAINT "CostCentre" FOREIGN KEY ( "CC", "CostCentreCode" ASC ) 
REFERENCES "dbo"."OutlineFiles" ( "Type", "Code" );
```

So there will be a relationship to the outlines table via a fixed value of "LN" and "CC". Or will it be easier to change the database to have two table and remove the Type column on the OutlineFiles table? I am attempting this in Sybase BUT we support many databases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you have a ["One True Lookup Table](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22One%20True%20Lookup%20Table)" (OTLT) anti-pattern and you are mixing entities in this table. You've found why it isn't a good idea:

- can't have filtered foriegn keys
- can't FK to constants
- can't have multiple parents

Your sample code above is confusing (you have multiple parents for the same Code column) so I'll give you what I understand

```
CREATE TABLE OutlineFilesCostCentre (
    CostCentreCode ...NOT NULL --PK
    ...
    )

CREATE TABLE OutlineFilesLocations (
    LocationCode ... NOT NULL --PK
    ...
    )

CREATE TABLE Assets (
    ...
    CostCentreCode ... NOT NULL,
    LocationCode ... NOT NULL,
    ...

    CONSTRAINT FK_Assets_CostCentre" FOREIGN KEY ("CostCentreCode")
                REFERENCES "dbo"."OutlineFilesCostCentre" ("CostCentreCode"),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Assets_Locations" FOREIGN KEY ("LocationCode")
                REFERENCES "dbo"."OutlineFilesLocations" ("LocationCode")
   ...)
```

If you have 30 codes to lookup you will have 30 lookup tables: this is correct.

If you insist on OTLT you'll have to add extra columns to store type in Assets and FK them to your OTLT. I wouldn't do this.

```
    ...
    CostCentreType char(2) NOT NULL,
    CostCentreCode ... NOT NULL,
    LocationType  char(2) NOT NULL,
    LocationCode ... NOT NULL,
    ...
```

Or use triggers to maintain the correct codes. I wouldn't do this either.

Comment: Sorry made a mistake with the Alter Table statement. Fixed it up. However converting to multiple tables seems to be a better idea as I need the foreign key constraints for MS Entity Framework to code generate the mapping for me.

Comment: @David Gray Wright: I've changed my answer to match your columns. Multiple tables is the correct way. OTLT is a bad idea.